# Destroying model which matches input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have an email field in a model.

I would like a path in this model, where a field shows up in the view, and when I type an email address, and that address matches an existing model, it gets deleted. For unsubscribing from  newsletter.

something like this:

newsletter_controller.rb

```
def unsubscribe(email)
  @newsletter = Newsletter.where(:email => email)
  @newsletter.destroy
end
```

in the view:

```
simple_form_for @newsletter do |f|
 f.input :email, method: delete
end
```

I got no idea how the view should work in the Rails Way.

Answer (score 1):

In `config/routes.rb`, I suppose you have `resources :newsletters`
Add a route for `unsubscribe` as following:

```
resources :newsletters do
   post 'unsubscribe', :on => :member
end
```

Check `rake routes`, you should have obtained a route path as `unsubscribe_newsletter_path` with POST verb.

Now, in your view:

```
=form_for(:newsletter, :url => unsubscribe_newsletter_path) do |f|
   =f.label :email
   =f.text_field :email
   =f.submit "Unsubscribe"
```

(Change it as per syntax of simple_form)
Now, in `newsletter_controller.rb`(it should have been newsletter*s*_controller), add the method as:

```
def unsubscribe
  @newsletter = Newsletter.where(:email => params[:newsletter][:email])
  @newsletter.destroy if @newsletter
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

I hope it helps. Comment with places where it gives you error or doesn't work. I'll try to help.

Good luck. :)

Comment: rake routes say:
    `/newsletters/:id/unsubscribe`
this shouldn't be newsletters/unsubscribe?

Comment: @RailsBeginner NO! Try changing route as `post 'unsubscribe', :on => :collection` then. :)